# Solution/approximation for $\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-\frac{(zn+1)^2}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

$n$ is an integer greater than $1$.

Comment: Can you describe what sort of solution/approximation you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks @CarlosEsparza. If we denote the sum as $S_n$, I would like to see the behaviour as a function of $n$. I suspect it behaves as $\frac1{n}$ but could not show it.

Comment: We do have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-{(zn+1)^2}/{2}}\;dz = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{n}$$

Comment: Thanks @GEdgar. I now realize that I simplified my original problem in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626207) a bit too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jacobi theta function.**
Definition:
$$
\vartheta_3\left( z,q \right) =\sum _{k=-\infty}^{\infty }{q}^{
{k}^{2}}e^{i2kz},\qquad |q|<1, z \in \mathbb C .
$$
So we get
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-{(kn+1)^2}/{2}}
=e^{-1/2}\vartheta_3\left(\frac{in}{2},e^{-n^2/2}\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to approximate from the Jacobi theta function the behaviour as a function of $n$?

Comment: Graphically, it seems that $S_n \to 0.6065$ as $n \to +\infty$, thus not behaving like $1/n$.

Comment: And probably $0.6065 = e^{-1/2}$